# Writing nested comments in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, django-comments

Django provides an excellent `comments` app. However, I don't want to use the other fields like `user_email`, `user_url` etc. I want to develop a nested comment system (just like [Quora](http://quora.com) does, unlike [Facebook](http://facebook.com)). But I can't understand how to go forward the template mentioned in the Django docs as its uses all the fields under the `comments`. Are there any useful articles/tutorials which could be of some help?

Comment: Have you looked at writing your own comments app?

Comment: Try http://disqus.com/ Implementation is as simple as inserting a snippet of javascript code onto your template.

Comment: I found this some days ago on reddit. Maybe it will help you:
http://maxburstein.com/blog/django-threaded-comments/

Comment: If you don't mind someone else hosting your comments then Disqus is a brilliant solution. It is even based (in part) on Django.

Answer (score 0):

One of my work mate wrote a threaded comment system one year ago, you might find some interesting pointers just by looking at the source code (or you can simply use that, or fork it).

here is the link https://github.com/pterk/django-tcc